# Trying to make an update query on a foreign-key field in a jpaRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys

I have UserLocations entity and Clusters entity together they form a many-to-one relationship (one clusters many userLocations, as described in the code). I also have a UserLocationsRepository interface extending JpaRepository and in it I try to create an update query, updating the id of the cluster for a specific userLocation row.

The problem is when I call userLocRepo.updateClusterId(clusterId, lat, lng) it shows 
    **Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query**

```
    @Data //lombok
    @Entity(name = "UserLocations")
    @Table(name = "user_locations")
    public class UserLocations {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        final private double lat;
        final private double lng;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="cluster_id")
        private Clusters cluster;

    }



    @Data
    @Entity
    public class Clusters {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        private double lat;
        private double lng;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cluster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<UserLocations> userLocations = new LinkedList<>();
    }



public interface UserLocationsRepository extends JpaRepository<UserLocations, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE UserLocations ul SET ul.cluster.id=?1 where ul.lat=?2 AND ul.lng=?3")
    void updateClusterId(int clusterId, double lat, double lng);
}

    @Autowired
    UserLocationsRepository userLocRepo;
    userLocRepo.updateClusterId(clusterId, lat, lng);
```

Comment: Thats not how you should update entities in hibernate/jpa. Fetch the `UserLocations` and set the `cluster` field on it to the new `Cluster`. Then simply perform the `saveAndFlush(entity)`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer but I need just to change a single field from the `UserLocations`

Comment: Still that is the way to go. You want to change the `Cluster` on the `UserLocations` and not the ID on the `Cluster`. Also you should always post the whole stacktrace here

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, you were absolutely right, that worked!